# Editing link javascript:open

Tags: javascript

I have a `javascript:` link. I want to insert there different values that I have in the variables `GEO_LATITUDE` and `GEO_LONGITUDE`, but I can not do it in any way.

```
javascript:open('http://maps.google.com/maps?q='#GEO_LONGITUDE#','+', '#GEO_LATITUDE#', 'popup-example', 'height='+window.innerheight+',width='+window.innerwidth+'resizable=no')
```

For example, if these variables are `46.15` and `50`, then the reference should look like this

```
javascript:open('http://maps.google.com/maps?q=46.15+50', 'popup-example', 'height='+window.innerheight+',width='+window.innerwidth+'resizable=no')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the variables are globals, your code would work if you removed the `#` character, used `+` for concatenation, and were careful about the quotes:

```
javascript:open('http://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + GEO_LONGITUDE + '+' + GEO_LATITUDE, 'popup-example', 'height='+window.innerheight+',width='+window.innerwidth+'resizable=no')
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^−−−^^^
```

If they aren't globals, you'll have to have the code call a function that has access to the variables.

Comment: thanks this is what i wanted, and another question is, can this window be made smaller ???? as a modal, for example 400/400 medley? and then it will open to full screen!

Comment: @AndriiHavrylyak - You can specify dimensions in the window features ([details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features)), but most browsers impose a minimum size. You can't make it modal, no.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work (  javascript:open('http://maps.google.com/maps?q=' +46 + '+' +50, 'popup-example','outerWidth=600,width=500,innerWidth=400,resizable,scrollbars,status')

Comment: @AndriiHavrylyak - As I said, some (many? most?) browsers impose a minimum size restriction, I think 600x600 or thereabouts. You're probably best off removing the dimensions entirely and letting the browser/user set the size.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use concatenation

```
javascript:open('http://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + GEO_LONGITUDE + '+' + GEO_LATITUDE, 'popup-example', 'height='+window.innerheight+',width='+window.innerwidth+'resizable=no')
```

Comment: Will fix it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Didn't see the inverted commas:)